# player movements in unity2d game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm just a beginner in unity 2d game development, this is my first game project.

In my game, player movement is working correctly in my pc but not working in my mobile.

Any idea how to make it work in mobile using touches , here is my code :

```
 if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) && transform.position.x < maxX)
    {

        targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x + increment, transform.position.y);
        transform.position = targetPos;

    }

 if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && transform.position.x > minX)
    {

        targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x - increment, transform.position.y);
        transform.position = targetPos;

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you really have a left arrow and a right arrow on your mobile while playing?

Comment: no , i didn't have one

Comment: @BharathiV You can split your screen into two area `left` and `right` or create two buttons and when you click on it, the player moves to left or right.

Comment: @BharathiV This [link](https://youtu.be/rMspwfprnz4) can help you.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions guys , i tried to add ui buttons and done some code work , now its working